# Gradle 6 migration settings.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle

I've got the following code in the `settings.gradle.kts`, which is works fine in `gradle 5`

```
rootProject.name = "server"

val pluginsRepoUrl: String by settings
val repoUsername: String by settings
val repoPassword: String by settings

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri(pluginsRepoUrl)
            credentials {
                username = repoUsername
                password = repoPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to upgrade to `gradle 6` but this code is not works and gives me a following error:

```
e: .../settings.gradle.kts:10:23: Unresolved reference: pluginsRepoUrl
```

The values comes from the `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: did you ever find your answer? We're encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Gradle 6, [the behavior of the `pluginManagement {}` block was changed](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#the_pluginmanagement_block_in_settings_scripts_is_now_isolated):

> Previously, any `pluginManagement {}` blocks inside a settings script were executed during the normal execution of the script.
>
> Now, they are executed earlier in a similar manner to `buildscript {}` or `plugins {}`. **This means that code inside such a block cannot reference anything declared elsewhere in the script.**

(emphasis mine)

This means that you cannot reference the variables declared outside of that block. To fix this, move those declarations inside the `pluginManagement {}` block:

```java
pluginManagement {
    val pluginsRepoUrl: String by settings
    val repoUsername: String by settings
    val repoPassword: String by settings
    repositories {
        ...
```